# Will the Java compiler precalculate sums of literals?

Tags: java, literals, constant-expression

```
int i = 10 + 20;
```

Is it true that the compiler will process this code, adding `10 + 20`, and the byte code is the same as for this line of code?

```
int i = 30;
```

Where can I read about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, and you can even verify it for yourself. Take a small Java file, for example:

```
public class Main {
  public Main() {
    int i = 10 + 20;
  }
}
```

Compile it with `javac Main.java`, and then run `javap -c Main` to disassemble it:

```
Compiled from "Main.java"
public class Main extends java.lang.Object{
public Main();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   bipush  30
   6:   istore_1
   7:   return

}
```

Clearly in the bytecode, you can see the compiler's optimization: `bipush  30`!

Answer (score 6):

Yes. This compiler optimization is called [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding). There's another compiler optimization called [sparse conditional constant propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_conditional_constant_propagation) that does something similar.

In general, there's no guarantee that a given compiler will actually fold constants, but nowadays just about every compiler for every language does this. In particular, the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.28) requires that constant expressions be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will be simplified [as required by the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.28) (thanks to @EJP for this precision).

If you want more resources and javac optimization you should take a look at [Compiler optimizations](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-2000/jw-03-javaperf_4.html) or [Java Compilers](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jch/java/compilers.html).

Another interesting thing is that even if your code is optimized during the compilation, a second optimization will be done during runtime with [hotspot](http://java.sun.com/products/hotspot/docs/whitepaper/Java_HotSpot_WP_Final_4_30_01.html#pgfId=1082363).

---

**Resources :**

- [Compiler optimizations](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-2000/jw-03-javaperf_4.html)
- [Java Compilers](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jch/java/compilers.html)

**On the same topic :**

- [java compiler optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391219/java-compiler-optimization)
- [How to see JIT-compiled code in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503479/how-to-see-jit-compiled-code-in-jvm)

Comment: You can rely on the Java compiler evaluating constant expressions. It is required by the specification, so that for example case labels that are CEs can be legal.

Comment: @EJP, I'm not 100% sure about that so I'll change my answer, but can you provide a link to the specification on this particular optimization?

Comment: The fact that CEs are allowed in case expressions makes it compulsory. See 15.28 Constant Expressions.

Comment: EJP, if you had written this as answer, you'd have gotten at least one upvote ;-)