# java byte code editor

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java bytecode editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395574/java-bytecode-editor)

I'm looking for a java Byte-code editor with following features minimum.

1. GUI - simple to load class files and view the byte code
2. Edit the java byte code and save it

Comment: There is very rarely a good reason to do this. If we knew why you wanted to do this, perhaps we can suggest a better alternative.

Comment: Yes, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @PeterLawrey just for the fun, I like to do some hacking on a .class file.

Comment: The simplest solution is to obtain the source or decompile the class if you have to, edit it and use the that.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I already hacked that way, I needed to try byte-code hacking also, this is just for learning purpose, try out different ways of doing things.

Comment: Hacking the byte code doesn't let you do much you can't do from Java so there is little advantage in doing so.

Comment: @Peter, it lets you do tons of stuff you can't do from Java. Though mostly, it's a matter of curiosity rather than practical use. But two cases where it is important are obfuscation and interfacing non-java bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

Google `jasper` and `jasmin`. Also check out [Disassembler Debugger for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539614/is-there-a-disassembler-debugger-for-java-ala-ollydbg-softice-for-assembler). I don't think there is any 'GUI' based implementation, although i can be wrong.