# Are there any JVM simulators / bytecode execution visualizers?

Tags: jvm

I'm looking for a visualization tool which could help explain how Java bytecodes interact with operand stack and locals.

Are there any?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539614/is-there-a-disassembler-debugger-for-java-ala-ollydbg-softice-for-assembler

Comment: http://blog.rewolf.pl/blog/?p=786