# How to run JMH using perfasm/xperfasm/WinPerfAsmProfiler

Tags: java, microbenchmark, jmh

Trying to run a JMH benchmark on Windows using `WinPerfAsmProfiler` gives the following error:

```
ERROR: No address lines detected in assembly capture, make sure your JDK is PrintAssembly-enabled:
    https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as the link suggests, is that you must install a disassembler plugin. There are several implementations. However, for reasons of self-censorship and copyright nazism, Windows binaries of most implementations are hard to come by. Additional info can be found [in this SO question (in which I've updated the suggested build steps and won't repeat them here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503479/how-to-see-jit-compiled-code-in-jvm/4149878#4149878).

The other issue you'll hit is that you must run the profiling session as an administrator.

Additional information about the system properties which configure perfasm, can only be found in the source code of `AbstractPerfAsmProfiler` and `WinPerfAsmProfiler` (at least, as of version 1.9.2).

A possibly useful tip: You can increase xperf's sampling frequency from 1KHz to 8KHz (and have more precise timing information) by running `xperf-setprofint 1221 cached` in any Administrator command prompt.