# Why Java SIMD (Panama) is slower than scalar?

Tags: java, performance, simd, project-panama

I have followed the intel tutoriel for SIMD in Java with 
[Panama](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vector-api-developer-program-for-java). I want to do some simple operations on arrays:

Here the scalar and vector loop from the website :

```
public static void scalarComputation(float[] a, float[] b, float[] c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        c[i] = (a[i] * a[i] + b[i] * b[i]) * - 1.0f;
    }
}

public static void vectorComputation(float[] a, float[] b, float[] c) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < (a.length & ~(species.length() - 1));
         i += species.length()) {
        FloatVector<Shapes.S256Bit> va = speciesFloat.fromArray(a, i);
        FloatVector<Shapes.S256Bit> vb = speciesFloat.fromArray(b, i);
        FloatVector<Shapes.S256Bit> vc = va.mul(va).
                add(vb.mul(vb)).
                neg();
        vc.intoArray(c, i);
    }

    for (; i < a.length; i++) {
        c[i] = (a[i] * a[i] + b[i] * b[i]) * -1.0f;
    }
}
```

When I measure the time :

```
float [] A = new float[N];
float [] B = new float[N];
float [] C = new float[N];

for(int i = 0; i < C.length; i++)
{
    C[i] = 2.0f;
    A[i] = 2.0f;
    B[i] = 2.0f;
}

long start = System.nanoTime();
for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    //scalarComputation(C,A,B);
    //vectorComputation(C,A,B);
}
long end = System.nanoTime();        
System.out.println(end - start);
```

I always get a higher time for vector than scalar.
Do you have an idea why?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `N` in your benchmarks?

Comment: For small (enough) vectors, the overheads of passing information to the vector processing engine will exceed the savings,

Comment: N is equal to 345600 = 480*720

Comment: @StephenC: I assume the OP is on x86-64, where all current microarchitectures integrate the vector ALUs *very* tightly.  It's worth using SIMD to copy 16 bytes, if the source wasn't already in integer registers!  Scalar FP math uses the same XMM0..15 registers as vector math anyway, like [`addss` (scalar single precision)](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ADDSS.html) instead of [`addps` (packed single-precision)](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ADDPS.html).  256-bit vectors will need YMM registers (unless Panama emulates wide vectors on top of 128-bit SIMD...).  XMM0..15 is the low halves of YMM0..15

Comment: If you're only repeating this 200 times, you might be seeing AVX 256-bit startup effects.  If this runs at ~8 floats per clock (1 vmulps + 1 vfmsubps), your benchmark interval might be as short as 2 ms on a 4GHz Haswell or Skylake.  That's still 8 mil clock cycles, so you're probably ok as far as upper halves of execution units powering up.  Agner Fog observed the warm-up period to be 14 us on Skylake: http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415#415.  (And BTW, 8 floats mul+FMA per clock isn't actually possible here because of the front-end bottleneck from load + store instructions.)

Comment: @K.Vu: did you warm up the JVM so it has time to JIT-compile the hot loop?  And did you check that the scalar version doesn't optimize away the work in the loop?  (Nothing reads the result).  A good sanity-check is that the time scales linearly with the repeat-count.  If it scales but not linearly, startup overhead is a problem.  If it doesn't scale, your benchmark optimized away.  If it is linear, then you might be measuring what you intended (but still no guarantee).

Comment: What hardware are you testing on?  If you include the JIT-compiled asm for the inner loop in your question ([How to see JIT-compiled code in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1503479)), and tag with `[x86]`, I can tell you why the Panama version is slower (if it wasn't a measurement error), assuming you're on x86 (http://agner.org/optimize/).  e.g. maybe the JIT compiler auto-vectorizes your simple scalar loop using a better choice of instructions, if your Panama code forces an actual multiply by `-1.0` instead of a SUB or FMSUB instead of ADD or FMADD. Or misaligned arrays on Sandybridge?

Comment: I have an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz. L1 cache is 128kB, L2 is 512kB and L3 is 4096kB. I have just set -XX:TypeProfileLevel=121 -XX:+UseVectorApiIntrinsics in my run configuration.

Comment: I have already done an HPC project in C with [SSE and SSE2](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE) and I was curious if Java could do the same.

Comment: You really need to write a [proper benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513259/581205). Java needs quite some time (seconds) till it runs properly fast and you benchmark seems to be just milliseconds. Forget it, use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), anything else is wasting time.

Answer (score 6):

You are using the wrong branch: build from the [vectorIntrinsics branch](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/panama/dev/shortlog/c33e709a35e5). You also need to use JMH to get proper measurements - [here](https://github.com/richardstartin/vectorbenchmarks) are some third party benchmarks written for the Vector API.

For the difference the Vector API makes to a dot product calculation, see [here](http://richardstartin.uk/vector-api-dot-product/).

Comment: How do you conclude the OP is using the wrong branch - I dont see that mentioned in their post?