# Why does this code take substantially longer to run in Go vs Java

Tags: java, performance, go

Been picking up Go recently and I'm a big fan, coming from a Java background.

I was comparing the languages in different ways, and was surprised that a simple loop counting up to 20 billion took substantially longer in Golang vs Java.

Was wondering if anyone can give any insight for if I'm missing something here.  This is what I did:

### Java

Wrote the below code, executed it from a normal `main()` method, built an executable jar with Gradle, and executed it from the command line with the command: `java -jar build/libs/my-executable.jar`

```
private void countToTwentyBillion() {
    long count = 0;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        System.out.println("On step " + k);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2_000_000_000; i++) {
            // Do nothing but count
            count++;
        }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total time took: " + (end - start) + " ms to get at count: " + count);
}
```

Across 3 separate trials, I got these results:

```
// Total time took: 396 ms to get at count: 20000000000
// Total time took: 393 ms to get at count: 20000000000
// Total time took: 388 ms to get at count: 20000000000
// 392 ms average
```

### Go

Built this file in Go, built it with 'go build' and executed at the command line with `./loop-counter`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    count := 0

    nanos := time.Now().UnixNano()
    start := nanos / 1000000

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("On step %d\n", i)
        for k := 0; k < 2000000000; k++ {
            count++
        }
    }
    nanos = time.Now().UnixNano()
    end := nanos / 1000000

    timeLength := end - start

    fmt.Printf("Total time took: %d ms to get at count: %d\n", timeLength, count)

}
```

After 3 separate trials, I got these results:

```
// Total time took: 5812 ms to get at count: 20000000000
// Total time took: 5834 ms to get at count: 20000000000
// Total time took: 5907 ms to get at count: 20000000000
// 5,851 ms average
```

I went into this expecting Go to be faster and ended up being surprised.  All trials were done on the same machine with the same conditions.

Can anyone tell what gives?

Thanks

Comment: what version of java and golang, also what bits 32/64?

Comment: This is an educated guess, but I suspect Java has optimized the inner-most loop away and all you're seeing is the JVM start-up time with a count to 10, but Go has actually executed it.

Comment: @IlyaBursov `go version go1.10.3 darwin/amd64` and `java version "1.8.0_112"` 64-bit MacOSX

Comment: @AlexTaylor When I first wrote this, Java definitely optimized out the loops entirely.  So I added the `count++` to the inner method and printed it out to verify it hits that part of the loop.

Comment: That won't necessarily prevent it from optimizing the loop away entirely. It can just optimize it to `count += 2_000_000_000;` You need to use [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for microbenchmarks.

Comment: @DavidConrad It probably wouldn't take so long if that were the case.

Comment: @shmosel That's possible, in which case you may need to look at the [code produced by the JIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503479/how-to-see-jit-compiled-code-in-jvm) to be sure.

Comment: When It didn't have the `count++` in the inner loop, it was taking 14ms in Java... effectively just doing the Println() statements in the outer loop.  Then it increased substantially to the 392ms, so it really feels like it's hitting that loop now.

Comment: I would like to point out that in your Go code you are using a ns call instead of a ms call. Getting the unix time in milliseconds is generally a lot faster than getting it in nanoseconds because they are two wildly different implementations.

Comment: Doing a  back-of-the-envelope calculation  it looks like there must be some loop optimization applied by Java. Suppose you have a single core processor with 3Ghz, that gives you a 0.3ns per instruction, lets assume that every increment is one instruction. So 0.3ns *20 bilion = 6s  wich is around the performance you see from Go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not an Go expert but java is definitively optimizing the loop.

Suppose you have a single core processor with `3Ghz`, that gives you a 0.3ns per instruction, lets assume that every increment is one instruction. So `0.3ns *20 bilion = 6s` is the performance one would roughly estimate without any optimizations in-place.

You can verify that java does some trickery here by supplying `-XX:LoopUnrollLimit=1` to your program. This tells the JVM to do almost no loop unrolling and therefore prevents most JIT optimizations from happening in your example.

Doing that, the runtime of your java example is now `6s` on my machine which is comparable to the Go benchmark.

There is probably an option to enable optimizations like loop unrolling in the Go version as well (consult the Go manual for that).

Finally, this shows again that micro benchmarks are tricky to get right. They often fool oneself in assuming things that are incorrect.

Comment: `-XX:LoopUnrollLimit=1` made all the difference. With it specified, it now gives `5,837 ms` in java.  Also to clarify - the post wasn't to make a judgement for java vs go... I was just really surprised in the outcome.  And it teaches me not to take everything for granted

Answer (score 1):

Here are some observations I made. I am going to show some Intel syntax assembly code I got from compiling this program. I am using [Compiler Explorer](http://godbolt.org). To understand what follows you don't have to know a lot of assembly, the most important element here is size, the bigger it is the slower it is. If I could I would make this post smaller, but the code generated is surprisingly huge, and I don't know enough about Go to know what is useless. If you want to see what each statement converts to in assembly the Compiler Explorer will highlight everything for you.

**TL;DR**:
The Go compiler is a disastrous mess in my opinion, the C++ code get's very well optimized, and Java is small compared to Go. JIT'ing may have a major effect on the Java code, it may also be too complex for a loop unraveling inline optimization (precompute the value of `count`).

---

The Go code compiled down to this monstrosity:

```
text    "".main(SB), $224-0
movq    (TLS), CX
leaq    -96(SP), AX
cmpq    AX, 16(CX)
jls     835
subq    $224, SP
movq    BP, 216(SP)
leaq    216(SP), BP
funcdata        $0, gclocals·f6bd6b3389b872033d462029172c8612(SB)
funcdata        $1, gclocals·17283ea8379a997487dd6f8baf7ae6ea(SB)
pcdata  $0, $0
call    time.Now(SB)
movq    16(SP), AX
movq    8(SP), CX
movq    (SP), DX
movq    DX, time.t·2+160(SP)
movq    CX, time.t·2+168(SP)
movq    AX, time.t·2+176(SP)
movq    time.t·2+160(SP), AX
movq    AX, CX
shrq    $63, AX
shlq    $63, AX
testq   $-1, AX
jeq     806
movq    CX, DX
shlq    $1, CX
shrq    $31, CX
movq    $59453308800, BX
addq    BX, CX
andq    $1073741823, DX
movlqsx DX, DX
imulq   $1000000000, CX
addq    DX, CX
movq    $-6795364578871345152, DX
addq    DX, CX
movq    $4835703278458516699, AX
imulq   CX
sarq    $63, CX
sarq    $18, DX
subq    CX, DX
movq    DX, "".start+72(SP)
xorl    AX, AX
movq    AX, CX
jmp     257
incq    CX
incq    AX
cmpq    CX, $2000000000
jlt     213
movq    "".i+80(SP), SI
incq    SI
movq    "".start+72(SP), DX
movq    $59453308800, BX
movq    AX, CX
movq    SI, AX
movq    CX, "".count+88(SP)
cmpq    AX, $10
jge     404
movq    AX, "".i+80(SP)
movq    AX, ""..autotmp_24+112(SP)
xorps   X0, X0
movups  X0, ""..autotmp_23+120(SP)
leaq    type.int(SB), CX
movq    CX, (SP)
leaq    ""..autotmp_24+112(SP), DX
movq    DX, 8(SP)
pcdata  $0, $1
call    runtime.convT2E64(SB)
movq    24(SP), AX
movq    16(SP), CX
movq    CX, ""..autotmp_23+120(SP)
movq    AX, ""..autotmp_23+128(SP)
leaq    go.string."On step %d\n"(SB), AX
movq    AX, (SP)
movq    $11, 8(SP)
leaq    ""..autotmp_23+120(SP), CX
movq    CX, 16(SP)
movq    $1, 24(SP)
movq    $1, 32(SP)
pcdata  $0, $1
call    fmt.Printf(SB)
movq    "".count+88(SP), AX
xorl    CX, CX
jmp     219
pcdata  $0, $2
call    time.Now(SB)
movq    16(SP), AX
movq    8(SP), CX
movq    (SP), DX
movq    DX, time.t·2+136(SP)
movq    CX, time.t·2+144(SP)
movq    AX, time.t·2+152(SP)
movq    time.t·2+136(SP), AX
movq    AX, CX
shrq    $63, AX
shlq    $63, AX
testq   $-1, AX
jeq     787
movq    CX, DX
shlq    $1, CX
shrq    $31, CX
movq    $59453308800, BX
addq    BX, CX
imulq   $1000000000, CX
andq    $1073741823, DX
movlqsx DX, DX
addq    DX, CX
movq    $-6795364578871345152, DX
leaq    (DX)(CX*1), AX
movq    AX, "".~R0+64(SP)
movq    $4835703278458516699, CX
imulq   CX
sarq    $18, DX
movq    "".~R0+64(SP), CX
sarq    $63, CX
subq    CX, DX
movq    "".start+72(SP), CX
subq    CX, DX
movq    DX, ""..autotmp_29+104(SP)
movq    "".count+88(SP), CX
movq    CX, ""..autotmp_30+96(SP)
xorps   X0, X0
movups  X0, ""..autotmp_28+184(SP)
movups  X0, ""..autotmp_28+200(SP)
leaq    type.int64(SB), CX
movq    CX, (SP)
leaq    ""..autotmp_29+104(SP), CX
movq    CX, 8(SP)
pcdata  $0, $3
call    runtime.convT2E64(SB)
movq    16(SP), CX
movq    24(SP), DX
movq    CX, ""..autotmp_28+184(SP)
movq    DX, ""..autotmp_28+192(SP)
leaq    type.int(SB), CX
movq    CX, (SP)
leaq    ""..autotmp_30+96(SP), CX
movq    CX, 8(SP)
pcdata  $0, $3
call    runtime.convT2E64(SB)
movq    24(SP), CX
movq    16(SP), DX
movq    DX, ""..autotmp_28+200(SP)
movq    CX, ""..autotmp_28+208(SP)
leaq    go.string."Total time took: %d to get at count: %d\n"(SB), CX
movq    CX, (SP)
movq    $40, 8(SP)
leaq    ""..autotmp_28+184(SP), CX
movq    CX, 16(SP)
movq    $2, 24(SP)
movq    $2, 32(SP)
pcdata  $0, $3
call    fmt.Printf(SB)
movq    216(SP), BP
addq    $224, SP
ret
movq    time.t·2+144(SP), BX
movq    CX, DX
movq    BX, CX
jmp     501
movq    time.t·2+168(SP), SI
movq    CX, DX
movq    $59453308800, BX
movq    SI, CX
jmp     144
nop
pcdata  $0, $-1
call    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
jmp     0
text    "".init(SB), $8-0
movq    (TLS), CX
cmpq    SP, 16(CX)
jls     89
subq    $8, SP
movq    BP, (SP)
leaq    (SP), BP
funcdata        $0, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
funcdata        $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
movblzx "".initdone·(SB), AX
cmpb    AL, $1
jls     47
movq    (SP), BP
addq    $8, SP
ret
jne     56
pcdata  $0, $0
call    runtime.throwinit(SB)
undef
movb    $1, "".initdone·(SB)
pcdata  $0, $0
call    fmt.init(SB)
pcdata  $0, $0
call    time.init(SB)
movb    $2, "".initdone·(SB)
movq    (SP), BP
addq    $8, SP
ret
nop
pcdata  $0, $-1
call    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
jmp     0
text    type..hash.[2]interface {}(SB), DUPOK, $40-24
movq    (TLS), CX
cmpq    SP, 16(CX)
jls     103
subq    $40, SP
movq    BP, 32(SP)
leaq    32(SP), BP
funcdata        $0, gclocals·d4dc2f11db048877dbc0f60a22b4adb3(SB)
funcdata        $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
xorl    AX, AX
movq    "".h+56(SP), CX
jmp     82
movq    AX, "".i+24(SP)
shlq    $4, AX
movq    "".p+48(SP), BX
addq    BX, AX
movq    AX, (SP)
movq    CX, 8(SP)
pcdata  $0, $0
call    runtime.nilinterhash(SB)
movq    16(SP), CX
movq    "".i+24(SP), AX
incq    AX
cmpq    AX, $2
jlt     38
movq    CX, "".~r2+64(SP)
movq    32(SP), BP
addq    $40, SP
ret
nop
pcdata  $0, $-1
call    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
jmp     0
text    type..eq.[2]interface {}(SB), DUPOK, $48-24
movq    (TLS), CX
cmpq    SP, 16(CX)
jls     155
subq    $48, SP
movq    BP, 40(SP)
leaq    40(SP), BP
funcdata        $0, gclocals·8f9cec06d1ae35cc9900c511c5e4bdab(SB)
funcdata        $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
xorl    AX, AX
jmp     46
movq    ""..autotmp_8+32(SP), CX
leaq    1(CX), AX
cmpq    AX, $2
jge     140
movq    AX, CX
shlq    $4, AX
movq    "".p+56(SP), DX
movq    8(AX)(DX*1), BX
movq    (AX)(DX*1), SI
movq    "".q+64(SP), DI
movq    8(AX)(DI*1), R8
movq    (AX)(DI*1), AX
cmpq    SI, AX
jne     125
movq    CX, ""..autotmp_8+32(SP)
movq    SI, (SP)
movq    BX, 8(SP)
movq    R8, 16(SP)
pcdata  $0, $0
call    runtime.efaceeq(SB)
movblzx 24(SP), AX
testb   AL, AL
jne     37
movb    $0, "".~r2+72(SP)
movq    40(SP), BP
addq    $48, SP
ret
movb    $1, "".~r2+72(SP)
movq    40(SP), BP
addq    $48, SP
ret
nop
pcdata  $0, $-1
call    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
jmp     0
```

I have no clue what most of that is doing. I can only hope that most of that is some sort of GC code. I looked up how to enable optimizations for the Go compiler, and all I could find was how to *disable* optimizations.

Comparatively I looked at a similar function in C++

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <cinttypes>

using namespace std::chrono;


milliseconds getMS()
{
    return duration_cast< milliseconds >(
        system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
    );
}

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    milliseconds millis = getMS();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("On step %d\n", i);
        for(int j = 0; j < 2000000000; ++j)
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    milliseconds time = getMS() - millis;

    printf("Total time took: %" PRId64 " to get at count: %d\n", time.count(), count);
}
```

Which without optimizations compiled down to (compiler `x86-64 clang (trunk (probably 6.0.0)`, flags: `-std=c++0x -O0`):

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 48
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], 0
        call    getMS()
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 16], rax
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 20], 0
.LBB3_1:                                # =>This Loop Header: Depth=1
        cmp     dword ptr [rbp - 20], 10
        jge     .LBB3_8
        mov     esi, dword ptr [rbp - 20]
        movabs  rdi, offset .L.str
        mov     al, 0
        call    printf
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 24], 0
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 44], eax # 4-byte Spill
.LBB3_3:                                #   Parent Loop BB3_1 Depth=1
        cmp     dword ptr [rbp - 24], 2000000000
        jge     .LBB3_6
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 8]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 24]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 24], eax
        jmp     .LBB3_3
.LBB3_6:                                #   in Loop: Header=BB3_1 Depth=1
        jmp     .LBB3_7
.LBB3_7:                                #   in Loop: Header=BB3_1 Depth=1
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 20]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 20], eax
        jmp     .LBB3_1
.LBB3_8:
        call    getMS()
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 40], rax
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 40]
        lea     rsi, [rbp - 16]
        call    std::common_type<std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > >::type std::chrono::operator-<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l>, long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >(std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > const&, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > const&)
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 32], rax
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 32]
        call    std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >::count() const
        mov     edx, dword ptr [rbp - 8]
        movabs  rdi, offset .L.str.1
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     al, 0
        call    printf
        mov     edx, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 48], eax # 4-byte Spill
        mov     eax, edx
        add     rsp, 48
        pop     rbp
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "On step %d\n"

.L.str.1:
        .asciz  "Total time took: %ld to get at count: %d\n"
```

There is actually a lot more code than that, but it is just the chrono implementation, in the optimized code it is just a library function call. I've also removed the implementation of `getMS` because it is mostly a wrapper method.

With O1 (size) optimizations this turns into:

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 32
        call    getMS()
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rax
        xor     ebx, ebx
.LBB3_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     edi, offset .L.str
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     esi, ebx
        call    printf
        add     ebx, 1
        cmp     ebx, 10
        jne     .LBB3_1
        call    getMS()
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rax
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 8]
        lea     rsi, [rsp + 24]
        call    std::common_type<std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > >::type std::chrono::operator-<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l>, long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >(std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > const&, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > const&)
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 16]
        call    std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >::count() const
        mov     rcx, rax
        mov     edi, offset .L.str.1
        mov     edx, -1474836480
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     rsi, rcx
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 32
        pop     rbx
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "On step %d\n"

.L.str.1:
        .asciz  "Total time took: %ld to get at count: %d\n"
```

O2 (speed) and O3 (max) optimizations essentially boil down to an unrolled outer loop (which is only there for the print statements), and a precomputed count value.

This mostly shows the terrible code generated by Go and some of the optimizations that occur in C++. But none of this shows exactly what the Java bytecode contains or what that will get JIT'ed down to if it is run enough times. So here is the Java bytecode:

```
public static void countToTwentyBillion();
    Code:

0: lconst_0

1: lstore_0

2: invokestatic  #2
// Method java/lang/System.currentTimeMillis:()J

5: lstore_2

6: iconst_0

7: istore
4

9: iload
4

11: bipush
10

13: if_icmpge
68

16: getstatic
#3
// Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;

19: new
#4
// class java/lang/StringBuilder

22: dup

23: invokespecial #5
// Method java/lang/StringBuilder.'<init>':()V

26: ldc
#6
// String On step

28: invokevirtual #7
// Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

31: iload
4

33: invokevirtual #8
// Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

36: invokevirtual #9
// Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;

39: invokevirtual #10
// Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V

42: iconst_0

43: istore
5

45: iload
5

47: ldc
#11
// int 2000000000

49: if_icmpge
62

52: lload_0

53: lconst_1

54: ladd

55: lstore_0

56: iinc
5, 1

59: goto
45

62: iinc
4, 1

65: goto
9

68: invokestatic  #2
// Method java/lang/System.currentTimeMillis:()J

71: lstore
4

73: getstatic
#3
// Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;

76: new
#4
// class java/lang/StringBuilder

79: dup

80: invokespecial #5
// Method java/lang/StringBuilder.'<init>':()V

83: ldc
#12
// String Total time took:

85: invokevirtual #7
// Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

88: lload
4

90: lload_2

91: lsub

92: invokevirtual #13
// Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(J)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

95: ldc
#14
// String  ms to get at count:

97: invokevirtual #7
// Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

100: lload_0

101: invokevirtual #13
// Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(J)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

104: invokevirtual #9
// Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;

107: invokevirtual #10
// Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V

110: return
```

Unfortunately at the moment I don't feel like compiling hsdis and JIT'ing the code, but it will probably end up looking like some of the C++ examples. From what I know about the JIT, it *might* be able to precompute the count value. But this code is a bit complex (in terms of looping) which may make it harder for a fast JIT optimization.

Comment: This answer might be more helpful if it were less vitriolic toward Go.

Comment: @Adrian I have spent years studying compiler and optimizer output, I have never before seen something as strange and complex as the Go output. It appears to have a garbage collector for code without objects. I don’t know enough about Go to know what it is doing, but I do know that those excessive instructions are causing massive delays. I gave it a fair comparison, I looked for ways to enable optimization and I couldn’t find any. If you know of a way to optimize that, or a Go compiler built on top of llvm I would love to hear about it. But otherwise the output I got is probably what the Op got

Comment: @Adrian I’m also in no way saying that C++ is a good language, it isn’t, it is notorious for memory leaks. I’m only saying that it has a very good optimizer. Go could also have very good optimization, the compiler I used for C++ - Clang - is built on top of llvm, which is basically an optimizer that makes it easy to create a new languages.