# How to analyze JIT-compiled code and detect malwares?

Tags: jvm, bytecode

Is there any tool or solution to detect malwares in JIT compiled codes. I think 
I can break my question into of the following parts:
1- How to see JIT-compiled codes of a java program (not Android!)?
2- How to analyze that? Is there any tools read?

Comment: “JIT compiled code” exists at runtime only. If it contains malware, some other code must exist in the same runtime that has placed it there. So that other code is the actual malware you have to care for. But if you like wasting time looking at the wrong end, [How to see JIT-compiled code in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1503479/2711488)…

Comment: Thank you, what about the second part of my question?

Comment: The “JIT compiled code” is just binary code. Any tool for analyzing native code resp. its disassembly output will suffice. The fact that it has been generated by a JIT compiler, is irrelevant at this point. Well, except for the fact that, as said, you are looking at the wrong end anyway.