# Can i detect instructions reordering by bytecode compilation log?

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, jit

I have next sample of code:

```
class Shared {
    int x;
    int y;

    void increment() {
        x++;
        y++;
    }

    void check() {
        if (y > x) {
            System.out.println("Ooops! y > x");
        }
    }
}
```

Looks clear? But main problem happens here when i am trying to increment and check in two threads:

```
Shared shared = new Shared();

        Thread writer = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                shared.increment();
            }
        });

        Thread reader = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                shared.check();
            }
        });

writer.start();
reader.start();
```

You can notice data race (instructions reordering in some cases?):

```
1. x++;
2. y++;
```

And now, i know about special VM flags, which can help me to print JIT compiler logs (`-XX:+PrintCompilation`).

```
...
    120  181       3       Shared::increment (21 bytes)
    120  182       3       Shared::check (20 bytes)
    120  183       4       Shared::increment (21 bytes)
    120  184       4       Shared::check (20 bytes)
    121  181       3       Shared::increment (21 bytes)   made not entrant
    121  182       3       Shared::check (20 bytes)   made not entrant
    121  185     n 0       java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle::linkToStatic(L)L (native)   (static)
    121  184       4       Shared::check (20 bytes)   made not entrant
    122  186       3       Shared::check (20 bytes)
    122  187     n 0       java.lang.Object::clone (native)   
    122  188       4       Shared::check (20 bytes)
    122  189 %     3       Main::lambda$main$0 @ 2 (19 bytes)
    122  190       3       Main::lambda$main$0 (19 bytes)
    123  186       3       Shared::check (20 bytes)   made not entrant
...
```

OK, now i can see how compilation of increment method was processed:

```
    120  181       3       Shared::increment (21 bytes)
    120  183       4       Shared::increment (21 bytes)
    121  181       3       Shared::increment (21 bytes)   made not entrant
```

**Do i understand correct**, that reordering here is due of [tiered compilation](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jrockit-hotspot/migration-guide/comp-opt.htm#JRHMG119)? Because `increment()` - hot method, JIT compiler profiles this information and use `C2` server compiler. And, as i think, reorder some instructions in such way, but in some cases optimization happens(`made not entrant`). Or it's wrong?

Also, there are some another logs for compilation:

```
    138  182       2       Shared::increment (21 bytes)
    138  184       4       Shared::increment (21 bytes)
    138  182       2       Shared::increment (21 bytes)   made not entrant
```

Comment: *"You can notice instructions reordering"* I can see no indication of reordering in that question. Did you perhaps mean to say that your program prints `Ooops! y > x`? If so, why do you believe that is an effect of code reordering, and not memory cache refreshing between the two threads?

Comment: If you want to *see* if there is code reordering, you need to look at the code JIT generates, so read this: [How to see JIT-compiled code in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1503479/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas
>f so, why do you believe that is an effect of code reordering, and not memory cache refreshing between the two threads? 

Because it's looks like instructions reordering.

Comment: It's a lot more likely that you're seeing race conditions between the two threads. But, only one way to be sure. Do your **research** instead of guessing, i.e. look at the JIT-compiled code.

Comment: @Andreas my question - is not a statement. I'am just researching. But from my point of you, here is not race condition, it's data race. And difference is big, because if we are talking about data race - it's looks like that CPU reorder some instructions.

Comment: I enhanced your `Ooops!` print statement to show the values. On first run I got `Ooops! y > x (59759 > 60415)`. On another run I got `Ooops! y > x (47619 > 48071)
Ooops! y > x (479509 > 479506) ...`

Comment: @Andreas

And? What u want to say?

Comment: I know how to fix such incident. But still, what u want now? Are you trying to prove your case? I still think that it's because of data race. And yes, what about bytecode compilation log?

Comment: Changed the enhanced print to store `x` and `y` in local variables, so the printed values are what is actually compared by the `if` statement. I get e.g. `2623 > 2622, 19040 > 19035, 22985 > 22984, 31192 > 29296, ...` is a single run. Those are differences of 1, 5, 1, and 1896, and that is a symptom of **data races, not code reordering**. You're right, it's a data race, not a race condition, I misspoke on that, but it sure isn't code reordering either. --- My point: Your claim *"You can notice instructions reordering"* is unproven, and unlikely, and is based on a false assumption.

Comment: I'm sorry, but *where* can we see that? Your question doesn't show any *bytecode*, and it doesn't show any *deoptimization*. What we do see is that JIT *compiles* the code (presumably optimizing it too but we don't see that since we don't see the code it compiled into), the exact opposite of what you just said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210522/discussion-between-slandshow-and-andreas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to Tiered Compilation. The problem also happens without it. Let JVM compile just one method `check` and see how it looks in C2-compiled code:

```
java -XX:-TieredCompilation \
     -XX:CompileCommand=compileonly,Shared::check \
     -XX:CompileCommand=print,Shared::check \
     Shared
```

The output is

```
    0x00000000031a4160: mov     dword ptr [rsp+0ffffffffffffa000h],eax
    0x00000000031a4167: push    rbp
    0x00000000031a4168: sub     rsp,20h           ;*synchronization entry
                                                  ; - Shared::check@-1 (line 11)

(1) 0x00000000031a416c: mov     r10d,dword ptr [rdx+0ch]
                                                  ;*getfield x
                                                  ; - Shared::check@5 (line 11)

(2) 0x00000000031a4170: mov     r8d,dword ptr [rdx+10h]  ;*getfield y
                                                  ; - Shared::check@1 (line 11)

    0x00000000031a4174: cmp     r8d,r10d
    0x00000000031a4177: jnle    31a4185h          ;*if_icmple
                                                  ; - Shared::check@8 (line 11)

    0x00000000031a4179: add     rsp,20h
    0x00000000031a417d: pop     rbp
    0x00000000031a417e: test    dword ptr [1020000h],eax
                                                  ;   {poll_return}
    0x00000000031a4184: ret
```

As you can see, `x` is loaded first (line 1), and `y` is loaded after (line 2). Between these lines another thread may increase `y` an aribrary number of times, thus making `y` seem greater than `x`.

In this particular case you've guessed about reordering of loads with respect to the original program order (in the bytecode `getfield y` goes before `getfield x`). However, as @Andreas mentioned, this is not the only reason why the program may break. Even if JIT compiler emits `load(y)` before `load(x)`, depending on the CPU architecture, it may happen that the first load gets a newer value, while the second load gets an older one, and this will be absolutely correct from JMM perspective.

Comment: Thank you so much for such constructive answer, Andrey! But actually, does it means that  Tiered Compilation may provoke reordering? Or such thing happens only by CPU level?

Comment: @SlandShow JIT may emit machine instructions not in the program order (that's what we see here). At the same time, CPU may execute machine instructions out-of-order. This happens independently on a lower level.

Comment: *"But actually, does it means that Tiered Compilation may provoke reordering?"* - Any native code compilation can provoke reordering.  This answer demonstrates that the Tiered Compilation feature is not relevant to your problem with reordering.

Comment: There seems to be a misleading focus on "reordering" as an actual thing, when discussing multi-threading. The real fun starts when a JIT compiles the entire loop to the equivalent of `x += N; y += N;` That's an easy-to-understand performance improvement which may *look like* performing all N updates of x followed by all N updates of y. Perceiving updates out-of-order doesn't always imply that updates happened that way.