# Java best practices for writing code that needs to be removed for a release

Tags: java

In C++ if you want to create debugging utilities or other code that you don't want to make it to production, you can use the pre-processor, for example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define debug

class Logger{
    public:
     void log(const char* message){
        #ifdef debug
            cout << message;
        #endif
    }
};

int main(){
    Logger logger;
    logger.log("Hello world");
    return 1;
}
```

will result in the following assembly code (generated via https://godbolt.org/ `x86-64 clang 17.0.1`, `-O1`):

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rip + std::cout@GOTPCREL]
        lea     rsi, [rip + .L.str]
        mov     edx, 11
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)@PLT
        mov     eax, 1
        pop     rcx
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Hello world"
```

removing the `#define` results in the following assembly code:

```
main:                                   # @main
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

As you can clearly see, the entire logger code has been removed during compilation. Since Java doesn't support things like `const` or pre-processor arguments (`#define`, `#if`, etc.), I wrote the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static class Logger {
        private final boolean debug = false;

        public void log(String msg) {
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var logger = new Logger();
        logger.log("Hello world");
    }
}
```

This is also how I've usually seen logging implemented in other codebases, however running `javap -c` reveals that the code isn't optimized out, despite the `debug` being declared as final:

```
Compiled from "main.java"
  public Main();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #7                  // class Main$Logger
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #9                  // Method Main$Logger."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: ldc           #10                 // String Hello world
      11: invokevirtual #12                 // Method Main$Logger.log:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      14: return
}
```

I know that java uses a Jit compiler but I couldn't get the output of the Jit compiler after following this tutorial: [How to see JIT-compiled code in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503479/how-to-see-jit-compiled-code-in-jvm)

Another method I considered was something like function pointers in C++:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Main {
    public static class Logger {
        public final Consumer<Object> log;

        public Logger(boolean debug) {
            log = debug? System.out::println : x -> {};
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var logger = new Logger(false);
        logger.log.accept("Hello world");
    }
}
```

but this results in the following bytecode:

```
public class Main {      
  public Main();         
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #7                  // class Main$Logger
       3: dup
       4: iconst_0
       5: invokespecial #9                  // Method Main$Logger."<init>":(Z)V
       8: astore_1
       9: aload_1
      10: getfield      #12                 // Field Main$Logger.log:Ljava/util/function/Consumer;
      13: ldc           #16                 // String Hello world
      15: invokeinterface #18,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/function/Consumer.accept:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      20: return
}
```

(Note: if I create a wrapper method around the consumer that just calls `consumer.accept(msg)`, the bytecode is basically identical to the first case, I'm not sure why)

Edit: I have used logging as an example, but I meant in more general terms (for example debugging), so unfortunately suggestions that are logging specific can't be used.

1. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if the debugging code can't be optimized out, even though the values are known at compile time. (the question is if this is even possible)
2. What are the best practices for creating code that needs to be removed for a release build?
3. If it's not possible to write such code, which version will have the least performance impact? Calling the method that has an if statement or using function pointers?

Comment: There is a language independent design pattern for this. Lookup dependency injection and null strategy pattern. You define an interface with report methods (this interface is totally unaware of logging, debug or release builds). Call it DebugReportingForClassXItf or something. Then you make two implementations one that actually logs (or writes to debug terminal) and one that does absolutely nothing. The first one you instantiatie in debug builds the other one in release builds and then inject the interface into the class that should generate info.

Comment: This pattern extends well to all kind of infrastructure code, and even allows you to completely change infrastructure (e.g. start logging to a log server i.o. std::cerr). And your code will have no if/then/else checks just sometimes a virtual call that returns immediately and this perfectly predictable by the CPU pipeline. So yes there is some performance loss but it should be minimal (better then a missed branch prediction)

Comment: I have seen dependency injection in Spring but that seems like a much bigger overhead compared to either method. Is dependency injection possible in vanilla Java or did you mean I should just replace every instance of `Logger` with `LoggerNOP` in the release build?

Comment: For logging, you'd generally **configure** the logger per environment, e.g to disable a certain log-level or logging root, not replace the logger implementation (though that is also possible, for example if you use SLF4J, it is a matter of replacing the SLF4J implementation). Most logging implementations are very efficient when asked to log something on a level that is disabled, or if the logger itself is disabled.

Comment: As an aside, using `System.out` for logging directly is generally a bad idea, as its methods are (internally) synchronized, which will introduce a contention bottleneck in highly concurrent applications.

Comment: Java does not have compile-time constexprs, preprocessors or templates (the generics are run-time). So if you really want something gone from built product totally then you probably need to build debug and production from configuration-selected or tool-generated different java files/packages.

Comment: Also, bytecode is hardly optimized, most optimization, including eliminating codepaths not run, or inlining methods is done at runtime by the JIT.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel check the updated question, I didn't mean logging specifically, although that is the example I used. Do you have any suggestions on how to see the Jit compiled code?

Comment: Similar solutions would also apply for other things than logging, as Pepijn already says have two (or more) implementations, and decide at runtime through configuration/dependency injection which is used, or by including (or excluding) an implementation on a specific environment. You can configure the JVM to print out JIT information, but keep in mind, JIT will generally only kick in when specific code/methods are run enough times. For example, see [How to see JIT-compiled code in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503479/how-to-see-jit-compiled-code-in-jvm).

Comment: @ÖöTiib Java actually does have a limited form of compile-time constant expressions. For example, calculations with primitive or string literals, or final fields or variables that are assigned another constant expressions will be evaluated and inlined at compile-time.

Comment: As with any perceived performance issue it is not an issue until you've measured that it is an issue. The things @MarkRotteveel points out are probably much more likely a bottleneck (and so is string formatting). Ideally a logger only quickly queues some data and returns to the caller then asynchronously writes it). So my summary, measure the perfomance (dependency injected or not) and address your bottlenck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title is about *classes* to be removed from production code, but your question is about *lines of code* to be removed. I'll therefore take your question as being in two parts.

First part: classes that are in the `test` directory tree do not go into production; only classes in the `main` tree do. This is the convention used by Maven and Gradle.

Second: if you do something like

```
private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

void foo() {
    if (DEBUG) {
        //...
    }
```

then the JIT will remove the condition check, as if the code didn't exist. See towards the end of [Java Language Specification, § 14.22](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22).

Comment: I have updated the title to "code" instead of class. I'm still unable to see the output of the jit compiler, but I'll take your word for it since it would be odd if the compiler didn't optimize this out.

Comment: @OM222O there's some discussion about optimizing out in the JLS section linked in my updated answer. Basically, a conforming Java compiler is not required to optimize, but the Java HotSpot compiler (from OpenJDK and others) does.