# In Windows x64 assembly, how to access an 8-byte integer argument to a function?

Tags: c, windows, function, assembly, nasm

I am working on an assembly function that will be called from a C program.

My setup:

1. x64 CPU
2. Windows 11
3. NASM (which relies on Intel syntax)
4. `nasm -f win64`

My question is: assuming the function expects only one (8-byte) argument, how can I locate it with regard to the `RBP` register?

My best try so far:

```
global _mypopcnt
section .text
            
_mypopcnt:  push rbp            ; Prolog starts here.
            mov rbp, rsp        ; Prolog ends here.
            push r8             ; Save rbx.
            mov r8, [rbp + 8]   ; Read the value to bit count.
            popcnt rax, r8      ; Count bits. 
            pop rbx             ; Restore rbx.
            mov rsp, rbp        ; Epilog starts here.
            pop rbp             ; Epilog ends here.
            ret                 ; Done!
```

The C program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int _mypopcnt(unsigned long long value);

int main() {
    int num = _mypopcnt(0xffffffff);
    printf("%d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

My (MinGW) Makefile is:

```
all: main.obj popcnt.obj
    gcc -o main.exe main.obj popcnt.obj

main.obj: main.c
    gcc -c -o main.obj main.c

popcnt.obj: popcnt.asm
    nasm -f win64 popcnt.asm
```

The stuff compiles and runs, but expected result (32) does not appear to happen.

Comment: Show your code, what you have tried, what went wrong, what happened, what you expected to happen.

Comment: OK, that's a lot better, but please clarify "expected result (32) does not appear to happen."  So, you expected 32, that's great, but what happened instead?  Did you get 42 instead? Did it crash instead? Did a bowl of petunias and a sperm whale fall from the sky instead?

Comment: I can tell you right away that  `push r8             ; Save rbx.` doesn't.

Comment: @MikeNakis 7...

Comment: Function could be `popcnt rax, rcx \ ret`, other stuff is not necessary, but if you definitely want to write this function with a stack frame and all that we can go into that

Comment: @harold So I can omit prolog and epilog alltogether?

Comment: For a leaf function yes (E: here's MSVC doing the same https://godbolt.org/z/oMq5G1PGv )

Comment: @harold `mov r8, [rbp + 8]` I tried also 4, 12 and 16 instead of the magic `8`.

Comment: @harold Is it in a register? If positive, which one?

Comment: You need to follow the function calling convention of the Windows x64 ABI. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-170#register-volatility-and-preservation

Comment: @harold That was charming.

Comment: You can also look at the thing MSVC does when compiling without optimization, then it stores `rcx` to its "home location" and loads it again in the `popcnt` with a memory operand like this: https://godbolt.org/z/Yh3GYTzMq (still no stack frame though)

Comment: @harold Actually, I was working on a bit vector supporting rank in O(1) time, and I tried to JNI with __popcnt64 instead of Long.bitCount. Needless to say, it did not pay off. This leads me to another question: is own assembly any faster than <intrin.h> __popcnt64?

Comment: @coderodde Perhaps you can see the machine code generated by the JVM JIT compiler, like this: [How to see JIT-compiled code in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1503479/555045) (I've never been able to get this working myself). Then you can check if `Long.bitCount` already compiles to `popcnt`

Comment: @harold At the very least, bitCount is implemented as a sequence of bit magic: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/2cd1ba6a52eafffa65d0f2532a07fff89f9cea0e/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Long.java#L1653

Comment: @coderodde When compiling with optimisations, the intrinsic should yield performance just as good as using the instruction directly in assembly code.  But keep in mind that if you wrap `popcnt` into a function that is called from C or C++, there's an extra overhead to that.  So the intrinsic is likely faster than calling into an assembly function.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be simple; only two instructions:

```
popcnt rax, rcx
ret
```